# Having a run -time error installing postgresql 12?

Tags: node.js, windows, postgresql-12

I'm getting this error installing PostgreSQL 12:

```
Error running C:\Users\guy\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_b69647f9a1\getlocales.exe:child killed: unknown signal
```

Comment: Try being more explicit, you can also post screenshots to make review easier